# Is possible to lock certain keys in keyboard during input in "edittext" box - Photoshop script CS6?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script, adobe-scriptui

I want to enable only keyboard input of keys: `+` `-` `[0-9]` `,` and disable rest of keys input in `edittext` box.
Also if `edittext` has already any `,` character, I want to block any further key `,` input.

```
var mainWindow = new Window("dialog");
var edittext = mainWindow.add("edittext", undefined, 0);
edittext.characters = 40;

edittext.onChanging = function() {
    //enabling only input keys [0-9,-+] from keyboard
}

mainWindow.show();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding your requirement for the comma (`,`) ... Do you want to allow the user to only input one comma (`,`) into the `edittext` field ? i.e. If/when the the user attempts to input a second comma it should be prevented?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider utilizing the following custom [ScriptUI](https://javascript-tools-guide.readthedocs.io/user-interface-tools/scriptui-class.html#scriptui-class) example.

It produces a simple `dialog`[window](https://javascript-tools-guide.readthedocs.io/user-interface-tools/scriptui-programming-model.html?highlight=creating-a-window#creating-a-window) that contains two [`edittext`](https://javascript-tools-guide.readthedocs.io/user-interface-tools/types-of-controls.html?highlight=edittext#edittext) elements.

1. The first `edittext` element has restricted input. It permits one comma **<kbd>,</kbd>** character/key to be input, and one or more of the following character keys only:

   **<kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>**
2. The second `edittext` element has unrestricted input. It permits any character/key to be input, i.e. it's as per default functionality.

---

**example.jsx**

```js
#target photoshop;

/**
 * @fileoverview Shows how to create a key restricted custom 'edittext' with
 * ScriptUI. This example permits only one comma `,` to be input and one or
 * more of following characters: `[0-9]` `+` `-`
 */

$.level=0;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Usage
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var mainWindow = new Window("dialog");


// 1. Example `edittext` element with restricted key input.
var label = mainWindow.add('statictext', undefined, 'Restricted input:');
label.alignment = 'left';

var edittext = mainWindow.add('edittext', undefined, 0);
edittext.characters = 40;
restrictInputKeys(edittext); //<-- Enable restricted input.


// 2. Example `edittext` element with unrestricted key input.
var label2 = mainWindow.add('statictext', undefined, 'Unrestricted input:')
label2.alignment = 'left';

var edittext2 = mainWindow.add('edittext', undefined, 0);
edittext2.characters = 40;


mainWindow.show();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helpers
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Determines whether an array includes a certain value among its elements.
 * @param {String} valueToFind - The value to search for.
 * @param {Array} arrayToSearch - The array to search in.
 * @returns {Boolean} true if the value valueToFind is found within the array
 */
function inArray(valueToFind, arrayToSearch) {
  for (var i = 0, max = arrayToSearch.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (arrayToSearch[i] === valueToFind) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * Restricts the character keys permitted in a `edittext` element.
 * @param {Object} editTextInstance - Reference to `edittext` ScriptUI element.
 */
function restrictInputKeys(editTextInstance) {

  if (editTextInstance.constructor.name !== 'EditText') {
    throw new Error ('Invalid class. Expected `EditText` class.')
  }

  var hasComma = false;

  var permissibleKeys = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
      'Minus', 'Comma', 'Escape', 'Backspace'];
  /*
   * Add a listener to the given `edittext` element to detect `keydown` events.
   * In the bddy of its handler function we detect each key pressed to determine
   * whether the key is permissible or impermissible.
   */
  editTextInstance.addEventListener('keydown', function (key) {
    var keyName = key.keyName;
    var shiftKeyIsDown = key.shiftKey;
    var altKeyIsDown = key.altKey;

    if (shiftKeyIsDown && keyName === 'Equal') {
      return;
    }

    if ((shiftKeyIsDown || altKeyIsDown) && inArray(keyName, permissibleKeys)) {
      key.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    if (! hasComma && keyName === 'Comma')  {
      hasComma = true;
      return;
    }

    if (hasComma && keyName === 'Comma') {
      key.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    if (! inArray(keyName, permissibleKeys)) {
      key.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  /*
   * The `onChanging` event is utilized to detect whether a comma already exists.
   * If a comma DOES NOT exist set the `hasComma` variable to `false`.
   */
  editTextInstance.onChanging = function() {
    if (this.text.indexOf(',') === -1) {
      hasComma = false;
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

- This essentially adds an [event listener](https://javascript-tools-guide.readthedocs.io/user-interface-tools/control-objects.html?highlight=keydown#addeventlistener) to a given `edittext` element to detect `keydown` events.
- In the body of the event listeners handler function we detect each key pressed and determine whether the key is permissible or impermissible.
- The [`onChanging`](https://javascript-tools-guide.readthedocs.io/user-interface-tools/control-objects.html#onchanging) event is utilized to essentially detect whether a comma (`,`) has already been input or not. If a comma *does not* exists when each `onChanging` event fires we set the `hasComma` variable to `false`. By utilizing the `onChanging` event and the `hasComma` variable it provides us with a mechanism for restricting the input of only one comma (`,`) key.

**Usage:**

- Note in the *"Usage"* section of the `example.jsx` file we enable restricted key/character input by invoking the custom `restrictInputKeys` function and pass in a reference to the instance of the `edittext` element that we want to restrict. i.e.

  ```js
  restrictInputKeys(edittext); //<-- Enable restricted input.
  ```

  If you wanted to enable restricted key input on the second `edittext` instance you just need to invoke the `restrictInputKeys` function again and pass in a reference to the second `edittext` instance. For example:

  ```js
  restrictInputKeys(edittext2); //<-- Enable restricted input for the second instance.
  ```

---

<sub>**Note** I tested the example provided in PhotoShop CS5 and it worked successfully. It hasn't been tested in PhotoShop CS6 - some changes may be necessary.</sub>

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about the rest, but to make it so that only the numbers can be pressed, you can change your code to something like this:

```
    edittext.keypress = function(e){
       if(e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57){
         e.preventDefault();
       }
    }
```

After that it would be a matter of simply finding the right combination of if statements for the rest of the keys I would assume. You can find a list of key codes and their corresponding keys by searching 'JavaScript key codes' on Google.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Keypress property isn't even executed, even when it is in onChange or onChanging event. It sounds like js engine in PS doesn't even recognize this. Thanks for help anyway.